# Probability to get into the segment of [1,5000] after iterations with the logarithm

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, number-theory

> Let 
>   $$g(x)  = \begin{cases}
>  x, if \quad x \in [1,10000] \\
>  \lg(\lg(\ldots \lg(x))), \text{  Iterated until the result is less than 10,000}   
> \end{cases} $$
>   and $g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R} $,  What is the probability that the number will be less than $5000$? If probability is defined as $S_n :=$ the number of numbers for which $g(x)$ is less than $5000$, then the probability is $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{n} $$

Comment: I do not know the English-speaking culture, but just in case, I'll write $ \lg(x) := \log_{10}(x)$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this function. Suppose we start with $x=10^6$. If we apply $\lg$ one time, the output is already less than 10,000. Does that mean that $g(10^6)=10^6$?

Comment: $g(10^6) = 6$ since we have the iterated logarithm as many times until there is a number less than 10,000

Comment: For example $ g(10^{6^6}) = \lg(\lg(10^{6^6}) $ because $\lg(10^{6^6}) = 6^6 > 10000$

Comment: @VladislavKharlamov Your definition of g isnt complete.You havent said what happens if you repeatedly iterate log on a number greater than 10000and  get a number less than 10000

Comment: It was meant that the function is equal to the result after all iterations

Comment: Your description of the function is not worded correctly then. You've written "As long as the iterated log does not become less than 10,000", but according to what you're saying now, you *do* want it to become less than 10,000. I'll make an edit to suggest a rephrasing.

Comment: Yes, I will be grateful! This is actually a problem with my English, do not hold resentment :)

Comment: Of course not; I'm glad I can help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limit doesn't exist. At $10^{10^{5000}}$, the ratio is almost exactly $1$, and at $10^{10^{10000}}$ it's almost exactly $0$, and it will continue to oscillate like that because the stretches grow so quickly and make everything that happened before irrelevant.

Comment: And how can this be proved rigorously?

Comment: @VladislavKharlamov: You'd need to show that $10^{10^{5000}}>x\cdot10^{10000}$, and likewise for higher towers of powers, with some fixed $x\gt1$. That seems rather obvious though :-)